# How to obtain connection information in a uprobe to SSL_write?

Tags: linux, networking, openssl, ebpf, uprobe

I have attached an eBPF uprobe to SSL_write to get data from the arguments of this function. I need to associate this data with a specific connection (destination hostname/IP and port). Is this obtainable from the SSL context that is passed to the SSL_write function?